# Why is the rank of a matrix capped in this way?

Tags: vector-spaces

Take a $3\times5$ matrix $A$ then we have that $rank(A)\leq3$. More specifically we have that when we think about the rows and columns of $A$ as vectors then any collection of more than three $3$‐vectors is automatically dependent.

Why is this true?

Comment: *row rank* $A$ = *column rank* $A$

Comment: Take four 3-vectors and form the matrix, corresponding to a system of equations for a linear combination of them to be 0. There aren't enough rows for each column to have a pivot, so there must be a free variable. (Write out an example and you'll probably see it more clearly.)

Answer (score 2):

It's true because the rank is the dimention of the image of the linear function represented by the matrix A. As the image is contained in a space of dimension 3, the rank of A cannot be bigger than 3